# The proper way to find Polls that belong to a Schedule

Tags: mongodb, meteor

*This is going to be a strange question. I think I know the answer, but after almost an hour debating the proper solution with my programmer, I need a reality/sanity check. Apologies if this doesn't fit the format on stackoverflow.*

We're using MeteorJS & MongoDB.

Our Collections are setup lik this:

**Schedule** belongs to **Event**.
**Event** belongs to **Course**.

The Schedule has the following fields: *_id, start_time, end_time, eventId, lecturerId.* 
Fields for Event and Course are not relevant.

Then, we have a poll-feature. Each schedule can have one or many polls. So, Poll belongs to a Schedule.

Now this is where things get weird.

How do we find polls for a specific Schedule?

My solution would be something like this:

```
    Polls.find({scheduleId: _id-of-schedule})
```

My programmer, who believes that Polls should belong to a Course instead of a Schedule, would instead like to use time and lecturer to find the polls. Something like this:

```
    Polls.find({
      lecturerId: id-of-lecturer,
      activate_timedate: {
        $gte: ISODate(start-time-of-schedule),
        $lt: ISODate(end-time-of-schedule)
      }
    })
```

Now, he was absolutely certain that this was the way to go, and not use scheduleId. He says the speed penalties will be neglible, and that this is somehow "more flexible".

He argues that it will be easier to display polls from earlier Schedules if Polls belong to the Course instead of a Schedule. Which is true.

However, is it really such a messy solution to do something like the following?

```
    courseId = schedule.courseId;
    schedules = Schedules.find({courseId: courseId}, {fields: {_id:1}})
    scheduleIds = _.pluck(schedules, '_id')
    polls = Polls.find({scheduleId: {$in: {scheduleIds} }})
```

Of course, a better way might be to store both courseId and scheduleId in the Polls document, and just:

```
    polls = Polls.find({courseId: _id-of-course})
```

The reason I'm asking this is that *he* is the CS-student, while I'm an amateur. So I'm very open to accepting that I'm wrong. But I want to understand how I'm wrong, if that's the case.

Let me know if I need to provide any extra information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question calls for an opinion rather than a factual answer. Both approaches will actually work. You could have a better discussion with your student programmer if you list out all the questions you would like to ask of your database in the future, most common first. Then you can test your hypotheses by seeing if there are any queries that can't be performed or if any important queries end up being too complicated and slow. You can also consider potential future improvements you wish to make to your system to see how easy/hard these might be in either schema. It's like chess: think ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Check my understanding:

- 1 course has many events
- 1 event has many schedules (could also call this occurrences)
- 1 schedule has 1 lecturer
- 1 schedule has 1 poll

If this is the case, I'd suggest denormalizing the event + schedule, so event looks like this:

Event: `_id, lecturer, startTime, stopTime, poll, eventName, courseId`

To compare how different lecturers performed teaching the same event: `Events.find({eventName: desiredEventName})`

Depending on how big `poll` is, you could make it a nested objet inside event, or make it its own collection. As you had it, it was a separate collection, so now your query would be:
`Polls.find(event.poll);`

However, unless it's huge & has a chance of exceeding 16MB doc cap, I'd nest it.